# trying to make a writing batch thing

Tags: batch-file

so ive tried to make a bat file where you first input where you want the text file then the name and then you can write adn after you write one centence you get askt if you want to continue or not but i keep getting stuck on every thing from theset /p questions to the variables

i also need help with creating and naming the file.

```
@echo off
title textfilewriter
color a9
echo where do you want your new file?
set /p c=input here:
cls
echo what should it be named?
set /p d=input here:
:start
echo input text and it will go to desierd txt file
set /p a=input here:
>>%c%.txt echo %rfn%
echo input watch and it will bring upp your text file
set /p b=input here:
goto start
if %b%==watch goto watch
:watch
start /wait text.txt
cls
goto start
:reload
start textfilewriter.bat
exit
```

i know its not done at all but that why  i am asking for help if some one have time to help me with the

> start /wait text.txt<

and the atoher stuff thats not working 
i will really appreciate it and i am sorry for all bad english...

Answer (score 1):

It can fail for a bunch of reasons (no check if directory exist, if file is writeable, if critical characters are typed, ...), but it is a skeleton.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    title textfilewriter
    color a9

:start

    cls

    set "where="
    set /p "where=where do you want your new file?"
    if "%where%"=="" goto endProcess

    set "file="
    set /p "file=what should it be named?"
    if "%file%"=="" goto start

:info
    echo.
    echo input text and it will go to the desired txt file
    echo.
    echo input "start" for a new file, "watch" to see saved text or "end" to exit
    echo.

:getLine
    set "line="
    set /p "line=text? :"

    if /i "%line%"=="start" goto start
    if /i "%line%"=="end"   goto endProcess
    if /i "%line%"=="watch" goto dumpFile

    >>"%where%\%file%.txt" echo %line%
    goto getLine

:dumpFile
    echo.
    type "%where%\%file%.txt"
    echo.
    goto info

:endProcess
    endlocal
    exit /b
```